# The term 'Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have powershell script where we are trying to get the details of ADF v2 and Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime i integrated the Powershell script in my VSTS CI/CD pipeline. but i am getting an error like the terms are not recognised.

But when i used same script and ran into my local Powershell ISE it is working absolutely fine.
Please share inputs on the same. Please find my script on below-

```
Write-Host "Login to Azure Subscription "  $SubscriptionName   -ForegroundColor Green

$azurePassword    = ConvertTo-SecureString $AccessKey -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred           = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($clientID, $azurePassword)

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $TenantId

$subscription = Get-AzureRmSubscription

Write-Host "Set "  $SubscriptionName  " subscription as the current susbcription" -ForegroundColor Green
Get-AzureRmSubscription -subscriptionname $SubscriptionName | Set-AzureRmContext

$Datetime    = Get-Date -Format g 
$LogMsg      = "Getting Data Factory Staus ...  " 
$LogMessage  = $LogMsg +" "+ $Datetime  
LogWrite $LogMessage

$dfExists = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -Name $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction Ignore

if($dfExists -eq $null )
{
    $Datetime    = Get-Date -Format g 
    $LogMsg      = "Deploying Data Factory  : "  + $DataFactoryName + " "
    $LogMessage  = $LogMsg +" "+ $Datetime  
    LogWrite $LogMessage

   #Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $DataFactoryName -Location $Location -Force -ErrorAction Stop
}

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer -ErrorAction Stop

$Datetime    = Get-Date -Format g 
$LogMsg      = "Getting Integration Runtime  Status ...  " 
$LogMessage  = $LogMsg +" "+ $Datetime  
LogWrite $LogMessage

Write-Host "Getting Integration Runtime to Deploy..."  -ForegroundColor Green

$irExists = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName  -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName  -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object Name -eq $ADFGatewayName

if ($irExists -eq $null)
{
    $Datetime    = Get-Date -Format g 
    $LogMsg      = "Deploying Integration Runtime : " +  $ADFGatewayName 
    $LogMessage  = $LogMsg +" "+ $Datetime  
    LogWrite $LogMessage

    Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName  -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $ADFGatewayName   -Type "SelfHosted"                          
}
```

Comment: just add `Install-Module AzureRM.DataFactoryV2` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: getting below error message-

Install-NuGetClientBinaries : Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "Windows PowerShell is inNonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available."

i think  "Install-Module AzureRM.DataFactoryV2" this will not work in ci/cd pipeline.

Comment: try something like: `Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted; Install-Module AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 -Force -AllowClobber`

Comment: I tried above one, but getting same error.

Answer (score 3):

here's what I've just tried and it worked for me:

```
Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 -Force -AllowClobber
```

this has to be at the top of the script. your error clearly indicates that its trying to prompt you something, but cant, since its a pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got next error with fix from @4c74356b41: Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.

One more instruction helps me to make it workable (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/79):

```
Install-PackageProvider nuget -force
Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 -Force -AllowClobber
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to install Az modules, not AzureRM:

```
Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.DataFactory -Force
```